# Kotlin how to save Radio Button and display values?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, radio-button

So I'm trying to learn Kotlin and have been using Android Studios to practice and learn. Currently I'm trying to make a simple activity with RadioGroup (with Radio Buttons), save the selected value, and then display how much of each value (radiobutton) was selected.

My question is, how do I print which button was selected, and how many of this type of button was selected?

I tried the following:

```
    //in MainActivity.kt in my MainActivity class 
    s1RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
        //if catButton was selected add 1 to variable cat
        if(checkedId == R.id.catRadio) {
            catSum += 1
            print(catSum)
        }
        //if dogButton was selected add 1 to variable dog
        if(checkedID == R.id.dogRadio) {
            dogSum += 1
            print(dogSum)
    }
```

Not sure if I'm going about it the right way, but the desired output is:
[image]

I have layout, ID's, clear button, and everything else working. **But I'm not sure how to use onClickListener event on 'SaveButton'** to save selected radio button and then displaying results (Ex: Cat = 1, Dog =2). I would appreciate any suggestions, or if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try something like this:

```
  RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
  // restore previous state
  rb.setChecked(lastButtonState);
  // set a listener
  rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // call this to enable editing of the shared preferences file
        // in the event of a change
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        Boolean isChecked = rb.isChecked();
        // use this to add the new state
        editor.putBoolean(BUTTON_STATE, isChecked);
        // save
        editor.apply();
     }
  });
```

I realize that this is in Java, and you're asking for kotlin, but a SharedPreference, is what you would need to save the radio button's state.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save all datam you can use database or sharedprefrence.
and if you only want just display value is clicked, you can make like this in button save.

```
String result1 = ""
String result2 = ""
String result3 = ""
RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById('yourRGidFromXml')
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton rb = findViewById(selecetedId)
    result1= rb.getText.toString()
    Log.i("ID", String.valueOf(selectedId));

  }
});
//this just for see result
btnSave.OnclikListener(view -> {
Log.i("Result1",result1)
})
```

you can copy code and android will convert that code to kotlin.